# Best ways to use the lazy load

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a very long chain of objects, all of which will be loaded lazily. We use JPA(out of luck on fetchmodes)

In a few cases we dont have to load full object graph, in these cases the performance is good. But in few other cases, we might have to load a full object Graph like below.

**Below classes are for representational purpose only**

```
FirstObject.java

@Lazy
private Set<SecondObject>
```

---

```
SecondObject.java    
@Lazy
private Set<ThirdObject> // may load 20-30 objects
@Lazy
private Set<FourthObject> // may load 20-30 objects
```

---

```
ThirdObject.java
@Lazy
private Set<FourthObject> // may load 10 - 100 records
```

---

```
FourthObject.java
@Lazy
private Set<FifthObject> // may load 10-100 records
```

.
.
.
(the list goes on)

**Edge case**

If you see, each child loads several children and there is no way to avoid. Imagine the user is trying to load the Firstobject.java now and he needs full object graph until the FifthObject.java graph.

```
firstObject = session.get(FirstObject.class, 10);
```

//Because all the children are lazy, he tries to initialize them like below.

```
firstObject.getSecondObject().size() // size() for load all the lazy children
```

//Now each of the child is a collection and they are lazy so he has to do the following

```
for(SecondObject sec: firstObject.getSecondObject()){
    sec.getThirdObject().size();
   //because third object needs fourth object we loop third and get all ffourth
}
```

All the above code takes around 7-10 seconds to run, and may be more if the children are more.

Question is, How do I load objects in this case? the user interaction is so erratic, that we may or may not need full graph.

I've thought about using custom JPQL/native SQL which joins all the related children and return Entity objects as one option, but wondering if all the effort is good.

Note: the user may not need all the information that is returned in the object graph, but, he needs only a couple of properties for display purpose(but he needs all objects though).

Comment: It's very hard to consider useful ways to optimize your data access without knowing anything about what the application actually does.  Why does the user *need* 260 entities in context all at the same time?  Could you re-design some screens to not be so dense?  Could you go back and get more data as the user tries to actually look at it instead of pre-fetching so much information?

Comment: Yes thats an option if nothing works. This is more like administration screens, they need all data shown at one place to make decisions.

Comment: The perhaps a scalar query that returns the data they actually need to see is a good option.

Comment: Scalar as in Native SqL?

Comment: HQL/JPQL are able to return raw values rather than entities as well, native not necc needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I've thought about using custom JPQL/native SQL which joins all the related children and return Entity objects as one option, but wondering if all the effort is good.

I think this is a good option for you. You have to summarize this information somehow in the database and minimize object creation in your app. Bringing all these objects into main memory just to perform some calculation is a bad idea.

Also, consider pre-calculating the results, if they're expensive to be done, to improve the time response. For example, if it's expensive to calculate some total, keep a total somewhere else in the DB and increase/decrease it on every inserted/deleted item.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'm surprised why JPA spec guys did not anticipate this scenario.

Comment: Well, JPA is about persisting objects :-) so I think their main focus is to narrow the impedance between code and storage. But, as you've raised this idea, I remembered that with JPA you can also project results into DTOs, which seem to be a more adequate approach to retrieve results from report queries. see http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-basic-projections

Comment: Yes, it is a good topic, but it solves only half the issue, i still have to load the related entities by calling recurring enitity.prop.size() method. I may go with JPQL solution. still waiting to see if there is a better solution. (dont see one )